# how to pass values dynamically in config file

Tags: database, spring, dynamic, properties, configuration

I want to pass the value in the value tag of the property dynamically from the DB. Is this possible in Spring? And how ?

For example in the configuration below.

```xml
<bean id="proxyFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="WSDLURL"/>
    <property name="address" value="WSDLURL"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
  </bean>
```

I want the properties mentioned above for the bean with id `"proxyFactory"`, i.e. `<WSDLURL>` and `<username>` and `<password>` to be taken from the DB and passed here dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a another Java class and make it as a bean in Application context and using Spring Expression Language, you have evaluate and get output of the method call.

XML configuration:

```xml
<property name="serviceClass" 
                 value="#{webServiceInfoFromDB.wsdlUrl}" />
<property name="username" 
                 value="#{webServiceInfoFromDB.username}" />
```

WeServiceInfoFromDB.java class:

```java
class WebServiceInfoFromDB {

   public String getWsdlUrl() {
      // Get the Wsdl URL from DB.
      return wsdlUrl;
   }

   public String getUsername(){
      // get the username from DB
      return username;
   }
```

XML configuration in application context:

```xml
<bean id="webServiceInfoFromDB" class="WebServiceInfoFromDB">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can setup property Place Holder with your properties file name that contains key-value pair.

`<context:property-placeholder location="config.properties" />`

The config.properties file looks like:

```
wsdl.url = http://server:8080/ServiceAccessPoint
webservice.username = guest
webservice.passward = guest123
```

Now you can modify your bean definition with ${key}

```
<bean id="proxyFactory" 
class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="serviceClass" value="${wsdl.url}"/>
<property name="address" value="${wsdl.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${webservice.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${webservice.password}"/>
```

Comment: Hi manjunath.. thanks but as i had mentioned and as @Betlista re-stated.. i want it from DB