# Spring dynamic datasource injection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, datasource

Is it possible to inject datasource host url dynamically??

My requirement is in this way, based on the userid the DB url changes.
So before creating spring jdbc template in DAO layer can I inject the datasource with host URL that is formed based on the input.

As shown below i would like to inject ***${dynamicPath}*** while initializing externalDataSource bean.

```
<bean id="externalDataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          scope="singleton"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=${dynamicPath}\tempDatabase.mdb;"/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: take two datasources and change them dynamically .. Instead of changing url dynamically to one datasource

Comment: i have around 50 users i.e., 50 MDB connections, i cant create 50 datasources :(

Comment: HAve you checked this   
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17190658/3030406)

Comment: @Babel: Looks like that would fit in my requirement but just wanted to know how do i initialize my DAO object with dynamic datasource URL and instantiate JDBC Template in DAO