# SpringBatch : dynamic datasource values

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have found this subject that answered to what I was looking for :
[how to pass values dynamically in config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186789/how-to-pass-values-dynamically-in-config-file)

The thing is, when I try it, I have an Exception..

```
    Error creating bean with name 'jobOperator' defined in class path resource [atlentic-Spring-Batch-common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobExplorer' while setting bean property 'jobExplorer' [...]
Error creating bean with name 'connex' defined in class path resource [batch-calendar-context.xml]: Error setting property values;[...] Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I'm trying to read a .ini file where I get DB info, then I would like to inject them into my XML datasource config.

Here is my xml,

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${DB_DRIVER}" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="${DB_PROTOCOL}:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_NAME}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="#{connex.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="#{connex.pass}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="connex" class="com.sponge.bob.calendar.entity.CustomConnexion">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

Then my CustomConnexiob.class where I use constructor to instantiate my attributs (it is not sexy, but I'm starting with SpringBatch) :

```
@Component
@Scope("step")
public class CustomConnexion {
    public String user;
    public String pass;
    public String base;

    @Autowired
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomConnexion.class);

    public CustomConnexion() {
        initConnexion();
    }

    public void initConnexion() {
        IniReader reader = new IniReader();

        setUser(reader.getProperty(Constants.MYCOMMON, Constants.USER));
        setBase(reader.getProperty(Constants.MYCOMMON, Constants.BASE));
        setPass(reader.getProperty(Constants.MYCOMMON, Constants.PASS));
    }

     /* getters and setters after this line (not printed here but they have the default name */
}
```

Is it possible to get this password and user dynamically using this way, I begin to lose my mind ?

Comment: No it won't. Nor will your bean be step scoped, the one in xml isn't step scoped but a singleton. Next the `DriverManagerDataSource` is a singleton and is created at startup. If you want different credentials use a `UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter` around your actual `DataSource`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer ! I tried to use UserCrendentialsDataSourceAdapter, but I didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Deinum,
 thank you for your answer ! I tried to use UserCrendentialsDataSourceAdapter, but I didn't manage to make it work. But your observation about the scope make me try something I tried before writing this post.
Finally I used this :

```
<beans:bean id="connex" class="com.sponge.bob.calendar.entity.CustomConnexion">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${DB_DRIVER}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${DB_PROTOCOL}:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}:${DB_NAME}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="#{connex.user}"/>
        <beans:property name="password" value="#{connex.pass}"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

and

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")  // <-- I changed this (it was "step" before)
public class CustomConnexion {
    public String user;
    public String pass;
    public String base;

    @Autowired
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomConnexion.class);

    public CustomConnexion() {
        initConnexion();
    }

    public void initConnexion() {
        IniReader reader = new IniReader();

        setUser(reader.getProperty(Constants.MYCOMMON, Constants.USER));
        setBase(reader.getProperty(Constants.MYCOMMON, Constants.BASE));
        setPass(reader.getProperty(Constants.MYCOMMON, Constants.PASS));
    }

     /* getters and setters after this line (not printed here but they have the default name */
}
```

my IniReader() just parse the .ini

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting username and password as null.

Remove calling initConnexion() from its constructor.

Add  below annotation on top of initConnexion()
@PostConstruct